# thrift php client x509 cerificate can not verify by thrift csharp server X509Certificate

Tags: c#, php, thrift, x509

using thrift php client with csharp server
i want to cerify the thrift php client,and i hava a client certificate,E.g test.pem.
thrift php client code:

```
$cer_key = file_get_contents("test.pem");
$cer = openssl_x509_read($cer_key); 
$socket = new TSSLSocket("server-host", 19140, $cer );
```

thrift csharp server verify code:

```
private bool DefaultClientCertificateValidation(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
        return sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
}
```

when i debugging on the server,the cert is null and the sslPolicyErrors is RemoteCertificateNotAvailable,
so i do not get the client certificate.
but the same thing in thrift csharp client and server work well.
how can i send the x509 type certificate which can verify by X509Certificate in csharp server on php client?